# Getting SSRS report Data in your asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I'm new to SSRS, I would like to know if it is possible to get the SSRS report data in an asp.net application in ordrer to get the value of a specific field (example: sum of assets, ...) ?

Is there any possibility to get the report data in json (webservice) or xml format, so that I can use c# code to get a specific column value ?

Thank's for the help

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                try
                {
                    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
                    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://pc499:80/ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS");

                    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/ChartProject/Map";
                    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex.ToString());
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

SSRS reports bind from a datatable. Find the datatable you created for the SSRS report and do what you want with the data before or after your RefreshReport() call.

Comment: I'm in the case of only reading an SSRS report so I only have the link of that report, I edited my post with the chunk of code that I use.

Comment: Unfortunately in your case I don't think there is going to be a very easy way. You can always output the data to an excel file but it would be hard to parse. I would either edit the SSRS report or try to get the data with a SQL call to the server.